# Data from image for FFT algorithm in Python

Tags: python, image, algorithm, fft

I have to implement program in python which will do fft algorithm on image. I can't use fft from library. I have implemented 1d and 2d fft in c++ so I have to only in some way change RGB values of pixels to some kind of Complex array for FFT.
I'm able to load an image and get RGB value of every pixel of the image. I have started some rgb to complex conversion, but I don't have any idea is it ok and how can I can go further. Any ideas will be helpful.

```
import sys
import math
import Image

def getGray(pixel):
    r, g, b = pixel
    return (r+g+b)/(3.0)

im = Image.open("triangle.png")
pixels = list(im.getdata())
width, height = im.size

greyscale = pixels

for i in range(len(pixels)):
    greyscale[i] = getGray(greyscale[i])


tab = [[0 for x in xrange(width)] for y in range(height)]
res = [[(0+0J) for x in xrange(width)] for y in range(height)]

for x in xrange(width):
    for y in range(height):
        tab[x][y] = greyscale[x*width+y] + 0J
```

[EDIT]:

I have edited my code. I have three 2D lists, each for proper RGB values. Let's assume that list with red values is R
I used fft from numpy, but Im not sure if its ok and how to make red value from it.

```
R = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
R = np.fft.fft2(R)
print R
```

this code will give me output:

```
 [ 36.+0.j  -4.+4.j  -4.+0.j  -4.-4.j]
 [-16.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j   0.+0.j]
```

What should I do to convert complex number to color? Any tips?

Comment: You could treat each of the channels separately (i.e. apply your *algorithm* to R, G and B channels independently and then concatenate results in a new RGB image).

Comment: Thanks a lot for tip! But I think I stacked with converting complex numbers to color

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean complex number to intensity (you already have a grayscale image). Just use the absolute value `np.abs`. If you want to this for a color, run it for the three color channels separately.

Comment: So what is correct way to handle this? Take RGB value from every pixel of image, convert to grayscale, then use fft and on the result use abs? And it should give me proper values?

Comment: Yes, unless you have relevant information in the colors, so it is a question of judgement. If you care about the colors, you can do it for all three in separate FFTs. There is a concept of quaternion fft that is used for the three color channels, but it really doesn't add anything to the understanding. I'd start with the grayscale, then check with the color channels. There are not many applications where the color channels would have dramatically different spatial frequencies from one another or the grayscale, but some special cases could be dreamt up.